# I want a user with "Administrators" role to see another line

Tags: asp.net, roles

I want admins only to see the 'Control Panel' link. Is that possible?

```
<LoggedInTemplate>
    Logged in as <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
    <a href="changepass.aspx">Change Password</a>
    <a href="admincp.aspx" id="admincpvis">Control Panel</a>
    <a href="logout.aspx">Sign out</a>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with:

```
<RoleGroups>
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrators">
</asp:RoleGroup>
</RoleGroups>
```

Thanks anyway!